# AWS EC2 instance URL unreachable when not connected to it by SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I ssh into my AWS EC2 instance. I have my app deployed to that AWS EC2 instance, using Docker.

I have my docker image registered in AWS ECR (Elastic Container Registry).

in AWS EC2, I pull the image and run it using:

> docker run -p 80:8080 imagename

and it runs successfully.

However, the problem is my EC2 endpoint (URL) is only reachable when I am connected to it using SSH.

The moment that I close my terminal (SSH), the EC2 instance endpoint is unreachable.

I want to have it reachable at all times as a normal website, what is a possible fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run your docker command locally but not in the background. So once you stop that session and therefor the container it's no longer available.

Can you try running the container with this setup:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 imagename
```

The "-d" flag will run the container as a daemon, in the background.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment @Marcin, but I'm only answering the question by OP. We can't determine if this is the most efficient way but at least we know for sure that container is running on an EC2 instance and not in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Elastic Beanstalk (EB), so you have to run your application through EB own docker system as explain in docs:

- [Using the Docker platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html)